# how to convert signed decimal to binary

Tags: matlab

I am converting signed decimal to binary reading value from file and after converting writing binary value in to file.

Here is my code but it gives me wrong answer:

```
fid = fopen('dec_bin.txt','r');
fid1=fopen('dec_bin_con.txt','w');
tline = fgetl(fid);
 while ischar(tline)
  disp(tline);
  abstline=abs(tline);
  if abstline==tline
  out_1a=dec2bin(tline,8);
 else
 out_1a=dec2bin(tline+256,8); 
 end;
 disp(out_1a);
 fprintf(fid1,'%s \n',out_1a);
 fprintf(fid1,'\n');
  tline = fgetl(fid);
  end
fclose(fid);
fclose(fid1);
```

my input file is:

```
 0 
-1 
1 
-2 
2 
-3 
3 
-4 
4
```

and when i convert it in to binary i am getting this output:

```
00110000 
0000110110100011 
00110001 
0000110110100110 
00110010 
0000110110100111 
00110011 
0000110110110010 
00110100
```

What I expect is:

> ```
> I'll add this part when I got time.
> ```

Comment: You should specify what is wrong and what is your expected answer.

Comment: my input file is 0
-1
1
-2
2
-3
3
-4
4 and  when i convert it in to binary i am getting this output:00110000 

0000110110100011 

00110001 

0000110110100110 

00110010 

0000110110100111 

00110011 

0000110110110010 

00110100

Comment: Are you trying to *convert* the numbers to binary, or are you trying to write to a binary *file*?

Comment: You must tell us what you expect in your output.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you are reading a line from a file using `fgetl` which returns a string not an integer. And then you are checking if it is a `char` using `ischar` and that is why the program goes inside the `while-loop`.

But you should know that `1` is not equal `'1'`.

Given your input, the `abs` function returns something like this:

```
abs(['0' '-1' '1' '-2' '2' '-3' '3' '-4' '4'])
ans =

   48   45   49   49   45   50   50   45   51   51   45   52   52
```

`abs` has no effect in this case, and it is not going to give you absolute values.
and then your code makes the following output:

```
dec2bin(abs(['0' '-1' '1' '-2' '2' '-3' '3' '-4' '4']))
ans =

110000
101101
110001
110001
101101
110010
110010
101101
110011
110011
101101
110100
110100
```

Also remember that, you cannot use `dec2bin` with negative numbers.

Comment: thank you,now i get it i was converting the string in to binary .when i convert it str2num  then it giving me right ans.